# Existe uma foma correta de se passar parametros para busca?

Tags: c#, web-service, api, rest, restful

estou fazendo uma aplicação Restfull e me ocorreu a seguinte duvida:

"Será que estou passando parâmetros da forma correta para este método?"

O método em questão é este:

```
[HttpGet("{initial}&{final}")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<SalesRecord>> getAllSR(DateTime? initial, DateTime? final)
        {

            return _srService.findByDate(initial, final);
        }
```

Esse método recebe uma data inicial e uma data final para que eu retorne uma lista de SalesRecord, seguindo meus critérios no serviço...

De acordo com o GET esta será minha URL:

> localhost:5001/api/SalesRecord/2018-10-20&2018-10-31

Tudo funciona bem! contudo, algo me parece errado pois tá muito simples separar duas datas apenas com um "&", existe alguma regra que eu deva seguir quanto a forma de se passar parâmetros em uma API RestFull? (para busca especificamente)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo as *boas práticas* de um `HTTP GET` você provavelmente precisaria:

- Utilizar o substantivo no plural, onde *SalesRecord* passar a ser *SalesRecords*
- Parametrizar as datas como filtros do recurso SalesRecords: `/SalesRecords?fromDate=2018-01-01&toDate=2018-12-31`

Então em seu controller você teria:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("/SalesRecords")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<SalesRecord>> GetSalesRecords(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
    return _srService.findByDate(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

Ou "formatando manualmente" a rota:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("/SalesRecords?fromDate={fromDate}&toDate={toDate}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<SalesRecord>> GetSalesRecords(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
    return _srService.findByDate(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

Comment: Outra pergunta: Qual a diferença entre só com get e get + route ex:     [HttpGet("/SalesRecords")] e [HttpGet] [Route("SalesRecords")]

Comment: Foi um erro na pressa. Na verdade utiliza-se a anotação [Route] pra mapear a rota. Fiz uma edição! @MárcioSebastião

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Aproveitando o embalo: Até mesmo IDs eu to colocando só na rota, isso é certo? Fazia assim→ [HttpGet{id}] [Route("Details/{id}")], agora to fazendo assim → [HttpGet] [Route("Details/{id}")]

Comment: Tá correto. O que você pode fazer é usar por exemplo [HttpGet{int:id}] para explicitar que o valor precisa ser um int. Sobre as rotas, dependendo de como estiverem suas Routing Tables, algumas você nem precisa definir com [Route(")]. Sugiro essa parte da documentação: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api @MárcioSebastião